# Is it possible to detect human body parts from images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, deep-learning

Is it possible to detect body parts such as head, shoulder, hand, leg, foot from a single image with OpenCV or other image processing libraries?

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyNtQ.png)

[Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe0FJ.png)

If possible please provide examples or tutorials, thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the existing papers here are a couple from 2012: 1. [Part-based models for finding people and estimating their pose by Deva Ramanan](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dramanan/papers/people_chapter.pdf) 2. [2D articulated human pose estimation from ETH Zurich's Visual Geometry Group](http://web.archive.org/web/20120327054100/http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~calvin/articulated_human_pose_estimation_code/)

Answer (score 1):

Human body part detection is an open field in research. Therefore it is not as easy as adding some magic method from opencv. However there are some approaches that work reasonably well.

Here are some examples: http://202.118.75.4/lu/Paper/T-IP/Pose%20Estimation%20with%20Segmentation%20Consistency.pdf, http://www.wineyard.in/Abstract/mtech/DIP/2015/bp/15D013.pdf,
https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/511304/2/3962_postprint.pdf

Anyways it is definitely tricky to get this right and it will certainly fail in some cases.